# How to generate 990 response EDI document

Tags: biztalk, edi, biztalk-2013

I have an EDI solution in BizTalk 2013 to store 204 EDI document in database. Users will see the details in a desktop application. Once they either accept or reject it I need to generate a 990 EDI response and send it to client.

Any idea how to generate 990 response document?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow! As written this question is too broad.  A rough outline of how to do this (this got too long for a comment):

You need to get the companion guides from all involved trading partners and come up with a mapping from the accept/reject message to the 990 message, and then send it to your partner(s).  This will involve having access to the original message data to make sure you correlate the response and route it to the correct partner.  There are many many patterns to achieve this, and quite honestly many bad ways; there are also several finer points to it since it involves EDI.  If you have a more specific question about messaging patterns involved here, it'd be better to ask about that in a separate question (with specific details about what pattern(s) you're trying and what issue(s) you're having, as well as reproducible examples).

Keep in mind that this is a non-trivial task, and any particular implementation of this task would involve localized factors that would make full details not well suited for StackOverflow. This question will likely end up being closed as such.

Comment: I'm not sure why it was down voted. I've completed the first part, I mean created the required parties and agreement and able to receive 204 Tender EDI document (using EDI pipeline). For 990 response user intervention is required like accept or reject the Tender. What should be the best approach for this. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is you just do.  Meaning, the 990 is just another X12 transaction your app has to create.  There is no automatic support for this, even though it's called and 'acknowledgement'.

You should probably do the EDI Tutorials and Videos first (["How Do I?" Videos for BizTalk Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/dd849956)).  Then, creating the 990 is just another mapping exercise.